# Importing an class and its functionalities from one file to another

Tags: python-3.x

I am basically working with python(beginner) on jupyter notebook and stuck on importing a python file into another python file.I am working on an assignment it has 2 files a , b  while making a class in file 'a' and importing that file into b to test the function that i have implemented in class of file a but didn't get answer
I tried this line for importing file 'a' in 'b' like this but unable to import

Answer (score 1):

To demonstrate you i created a little sample.
Both files are in the same directory.

```py
# file: a.py
class A:
    def printing_method(self):
        """this is the method that prints the output"""
        print('Class A said: hello world')
```

```py
# file: b.py
# import class A from module a
from a import A


class B:
    def not_printing_method(self):
        """here we create an instance of the imported class A"""
        a_instance = A()
        # call the method of class B to print
        a_instance.printing_method()


# Create an instance of class B
b_instance = B()

# Call the printing method of class A through the not printing method of class B
b_instance.not_printing_method()
```